# Results of xfor loop failing with numerical arguments

Tags: loops

I am trying to write a macro that selects an item from a comma separated list,
`\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}` results in `B`. I am using the `xfor` package to process the list, but would try `etoolbox` if that offered a better solution. Now for the problem: the macro works fine for plain text, however if the item is a number, I get an unclosed `\ifnum`.

```
! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line 29.
 
                \fi
```

Here is the minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfor}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcount\select@count
\newcount\select@i
\newcommand\select[2]{%
    \select@i=1\select@count=0%
    \@for\@@select@item:={#2}\do{\advance\select@count by1}%
    \ifnum#1>\select@count??\else%
    \@for\@@select@item:={#2}\do{%
      \advance\select@i by1%
      \ifnum#1<1??\@endfortrue\fi%
      \ifnum\select@i=#1\@@select@item\@endfortrue\fi%
    }%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
%  these do not work
%  \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
%  \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{document}
```

Any thought on why it fails with numbers? Do I need to protect my list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main error is in the line

```
\ifnum\select@i=#1\@@select@item\@endfortrue\fi%
```

When `\@@select@item` the lookup for the number is not finished and TeX keeps expanding until finding something that's not a digit; when `\@@select@item` is `1`, it's easy to predict chaos. A better style is

```
\ifnum#1=\select@i\@@select@item\@endfortrue\fi
```

because `\select@i` is a counter, so the `<number>` it represents is complete.

However you're off by one: in case of non numeric input the premature expansion of `\@@select@item` finds the *preceding* item.

Here's a working version; in order to avoid problems with expansion following a constant it's better to use `\@ne` for the constant 1 and `\z@` for the constant 0.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfor}

\makeatletter
\newcount\select@count
\newcount\select@i
\newcommand\select[2]{%
    \select@i=\z@\select@count=\z@
    \@for\@@select@item:={#2}\do{\advance\select@count by\@ne}%
    \ifnum#1>\select@count??\else
      \@for\@@select@item:={#2}\do{%
        \advance\select@i by\@ne
        \ifnum#1<1??\@endfortrue\fi
        \ifnum#1=\select@i\@@select@item\@endfortrue\fi
      }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{0}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{5}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{10}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Note that the initial setting of `\select@i` is at 0.

[image]

An alternative version with only one counter and only one cycle:

```
\makeatletter
\newcount\select@count
\newcommand\select[2]{%
  \ifnum#1<\@ne??\else
  \select@count=\z@
  \@for\@@select@item:={#2,\@@nil}\do{%
    \advance\select@count\@ne
    \expandafter\ifx\@@select@item\@@nil
      ??\@endfortrue
    \else
      \ifnum#1=\select@count
        \@@select@item\@endfortrue
      \fi
    \fi}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

---

The inevitable LaTeX3 solution, which has a big advantage on the `\@for` based ones: it's fully expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \select { m m }
 {
  \egreg_select:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \egreg_select:nn #1 #2
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { #1 < 1 }
    ||
    \int_compare_p:n { #1 > \clist_count:n { #2 } }
   }
   {
    ??
   }
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
  %these do not work
  \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{itemize}

% Let's show it's fully expandable!
\edef\x{\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}}\x

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to give a macro for the second argument, you need to expand it before the functions come into action.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \select { m m }
 {
  \egreg_select:on { #2 } { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \egreg_select:nn #1 #2
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { #2 < 1 }
    ||
    \int_compare_p:n { #2 > \clist_count:n { #1 } }
   }
   {
    ??
   }
   {
    \clist_item:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_select:nn { o }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\alist}{X,Y,Z}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
  %these do not work
  \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{itemize}

\verb+\select{2}{\alist}+ gives \select{2}{\alist}

% Let's show it's fully expandable!
\edef\x{\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}}\x

\end{document}
```

Note that for efficiency I inverted the order of the arguments in `\egreg_select:nn` (the first is the list, the second is the number; but this doesn't change the syntax for the user level command.

Comment: I've been too slow...

Comment: Where does one find/learn the latex3 commands like \clist_count, etc.?

Comment: @user39714 `texdoc interface3` on your machine

Comment: I still have alot of trouble getting my head around expansions. I tried to replace the clist with a cs (\def\myList{1,2,3,4,5}) and \select{2}{\myList}, which does not work because it thinks there is only one item?

Comment: @user39714 You can change `\clist_item:nn` into `\clist_item:on` and add, just before `\ExplSyntaxOff`, the magic line `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { o }`

Comment: perhaps I am misunderstanding. I see where the "o" is to expand the command once, but this solution still does not work. Here is the updated code  `\ExplSyntaxOn  \DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand  \select { m m }  {\dgmn_select:nn { #1 } { #2 }}  
  
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_item:nn { o }  
\cs_new:Npn \dgmn_select:nn #1 #2  
{  
   \bool_if:nTF  
    {\int_compare_p:n { #1 < 1 } || \int_compare_p:n { #1 > \clist_count:n { #2 }}}  
    {??}{\clist_item:on { #2 }{ #1 }}  
}  
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @user39714 I was wrong, sorry; I'll update my answer.

Comment: I figured it out, you also have to get \clist_count to expand the list before counting it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter
\newif\ifprinted
\newcounter{select@i}
\newcommand\select[2]{% \select{<num>}{<csv list>}
  \printedfalse% Nothing has been printed
  \setcounter{select@i}{0}% List starts from 1
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{select@i}% Next item
    \ifnum\value{select@i}=#1\relax##1\printedtrue\fi}% How each item should be processed
  \docsvlist{#2}% Process list
  \ifprinted\else??\fi% No number was printed
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{5,4,3,2,1}+ gives \select{1}{5,4,3,2,1}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{5,4,3,2,1}+ gives \select{2}{5,4,3,2,1}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

There is no need to count the number of items in the list. Only print out `??` if `\printedfalse` (no number has been printed).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest l3clist which provides the function `\clist_item:Nn`. A list starts add the indice 1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \select { m m }
 {
  \clist_item:nn { #2 } { #1 + 1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
  %these do not work
  \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros from [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) to accomplish this in an expandable way.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}% \http://ctan.org/pkg/xint

% if #1 is too big, returns nothing; if #1 is < 0, returns from the tail
% if #1=0 returns the number of items

\newcommand{\select}[2]{\xintNthElt {#1}{\xintCSVtoList{#2}}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \verb+\select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{0}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{1}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{2}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{5}{A,B,C,D,E}
  \item \verb+\select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}+ gives \select{10}{A,B,C,D,E}
%  these do  work
 \item \verb+\select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{1}{1,2,3,4,5}
 \item \verb+\select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}+ gives \select{2}{1,2,3,4,5}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

> [image: select]